# Customizing or adding CMake PostBuild Rules for Xcode

Tags: xcode, cmake

I have used CMake 2.8.10 to generate an XCode 4 project on OS X 10.8.

I would now like to instruct CMake to create the project with a custom version of the "CMake PostBuild" build phase to run an additional scripts, and/or have CMake create an additional "Run Script" build phase at the end of the target build process when it generates the project.

The goal is to not have to manually add the script every time I regenerate the project.

Is there a way to automatically add a Run Script build phase on to an XCode project target from CMake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot do this.  Custom command is not meant for this either.

Comment: Is this not exactly what [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) is for? [Adding a PostBuild or PreBuild Script](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcmake%5Dadd_custom_command)?